# Question about Lipschitz function with $\|·\|_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Could someone tell me if this  is Lipschitz function?

$F(x,y)=\sin(x)\arctan(y)$. I think yes with $L=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (using $\|·\|_\infty$) but I am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\nabla F$ is bounded, then $F$ is Lipschitz.